# How to delete multiple rows using LINQ in linq2db Templates based on two tables?

Tags: linq, linq2db

I've two tables `Product` and `user`. Now, i want to delete multiple records at a time with a relation like: i want to delete all the products related to particular user.

I've delete multiple records code in linq2db Templates

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  db.Product
  .Where(p => p.Discontinued)
  .Delete();
}
```

But, how to relate that user table to this code?

Source: https://linq2db.github.io/#delete

Comment: But, I there it's deleting all the rows On The Go, Not using foreach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following solution to delete multiple rows using LINQ in linq2db Templates based on two tables:

```
(
    from p in db.Product
    join u in db.User on ... some join ...
    select p
)
.Delete();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  var deletionList=db.Product
                     .Where(p => p.Discontinued).AsEnumerable();
  db.Product.RemoveRange(deletionList);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This syntax is not for Lin2DB, the OP clearly asked for Linq2DB. @Sumit